# How do I solve an error with wordcloud "argument y missing"

Tags: r, word-cloud

The dataset I'm using is from https://sexualitics.github.io/ under the xhamster section. Here is the initial code:

```
head(xhamster) # Need to change upload_date into a date column, then add new column containing year
xhamster$upload_date<-as.Date(xhamster$upload_date,format="%d/%m/%Y")
xhamster$Year<-year(ymd(xhamster$upload_date)) #Adds new column containing just the year
xhamster$Year<-as.integer(xhamster$Year) # Changing new Year variable into an interger
head(xhamster) # Check changes made correctly

Yr2007<-xhamster%>%
  filter_at(vars(Year),any_vars(.%in%c("2007")))
Yr2008<-xhamster%>%
  filter_at(vars(Year),any_vars(.%in%c("2008")))
Yr2009<-xhamster%>%
  filter_at(vars(Year),any_vars(.%in%c("2009")))
Yr2010<-xhamster%>%
  filter_at(vars(Year),any_vars(.%in%c("2010")))
Yr2011<-xhamster%>%
  filter_at(vars(Year),any_vars(.%in%c("2011")))
Yr2012<-xhamster%>%
  filter_at(vars(Year),any_vars(.%in%c("2012")))
Yr2013<-xhamster%>%
  filter_at(vars(Year),any_vars(.%in%c("2013")))
```

I just wondered if I could get some assistance on this; basically it seems to work fine but still relays an error which I would like to solve before submitting.

```
Corpus2007<-Corpus(VectorSource(Yr2007$channels))
Corpus2007<-gsub('[])(;:#%$^*\\~{}[&+=@/"`|<>_]+'," ", Corpus2007)

set.seed(1234)
textplot(wordcloud(Corpus2007,min_count=6,random.order = FALSE,rotation=0.25,
                   colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(8,"Dark2")))

Error in plot(x, y, type = "n", ...) : 
  argument "y" is missing, with no default
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Comment: [1] Try typing warnings(), like the message says. [2] There are multiple `wordcloud` functions, did you use the one from the `quanteda` package? [3] Without some example data, it is hard to say what is going wrong. Can you include a minimal dataset that reproduces the error?

Comment: I've just edited the post to reflect the basic exploratory data analysis that has been done before creating a corpus. I did try adding the `freq` function but that seemed to produce more errors. The `warnings` were confusing to understand as well - sorry I am very new to R!